# How to implement custom animation page transitions in XAML in a UWP app like iOS?

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, transition

I really like the look of how page transitions look between a parent/child page on iOS with the combination of a UI navigation controller with its child view controllers.   I like the animation of the parent page sliding over to the left as the child page slides slowly in from the right.  This is used in a lot of iOS apps and in the iOS settings pages.
I'd like to implement this type of navigation animation for UWP Page Frames in XAML.
Does anyone know how to create those types of page transitions and also allow then to be reversible so that if you navigate to a page and then use Frame.GoBack() to go Back, the animation can toggle those pages back and forth?

Thanks a lot,
  Rick

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a few lines of code in your navigation destination page this way :

```
<Page
x:Class="UwpTransition.Pages.Page1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UwpTransition.Pages"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<!--Adding Animation-->
<Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <EdgeUIThemeTransition Edge="Left"
                               x:Name="EntranceAnimation" />
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
</Page>
```

And in the code behind use this code to make the transition entering from right instead of left :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
        EntranceAnimation.Edge = EdgeTransitionLocation.Right;

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Connected Animations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/connected-animation

While not exactly what you are looking for, Connected Animations can be used to build immersive experiences in line with Fluent Design. Instead of copying the iOS experience, you want the transition to feel native to Windows users.

Answer (score 0):

This way of horizontal sliding works better and smooth than all the above mentioned ways:

```cs
// Navigate to the right, ie. from LeftPage to RightPage

myFrame.Navigate(typeof(RightPage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromRight } );

// Navigate to the left, ie. from RightPage to LeftPage

myFrame.Navigate(typeof(LeftPage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo() { Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromLeft } );
```

Please check [horizontal-slide, ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/motion/page-transitions#horizontal-slide)